# SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION TimeRemaining max value

Tags: winapi

It seems like the TimeRemaining has different max values on different computers. for example, on my desk it is 32bit while in another with the same OS (win7 64bit) they have it at 16bit.

Is there any way to determine the max value?

Thanks.

Comment: `TimeRemaining` is an unsigned long (ULONG), which is never 16-bit in any modern version of Windows. Where are you getting your information?

Comment: Simply printing to the console the value while the user works works with the computer. as I said, in some cases it will be 4294967295 and in others it will be a lower value. as far as I remember it was 32767.

But assume I'm totally off the chart with 16 and 32 bits. my question is how can I tell what will the max value be in each platform I'm running the program on?

Comment: You didn't "say" that anywhere, and "simply printing to the console" does not tell you whether an integer is 16/32 bit. A ULONG is an unsigned 32-bit integer on both Win32 and Win64, and has a max value of 4294967295 on both platforms; it doesn't change. An unsigned 32-bit integer is an unsigned 32-bit integer. The type is declared as ULONG on all versions of Windows.

Comment: Either I don't have the mental capacity to understand what you are saying. or I was just writing the question so bad it can not be understood clearly.

I'm NOT asking what is the maximum value of 32 or 16 bit. I'm asking if there is a way to tell what would be the non idle value (max) of the TimeRemaining  on each (win7) unique environment as it is not the same.

Comment: From the [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373217(v=vs.85).aspx), it seems like you might be able to determine the maximum by examining the `Idleness` field. It's just possible that `TimeRemaining` is equal to `(Idleness * max)/100`, or something like that. At least, that's what I'd try. The real question, though, is why it should matter what the max value is.

Comment: @JimMischel the idleness formula seems way more complicated than that.  you could leave the computer without input for 5 minuets and it will dance somewhere around the high 90's. in fact, you could have some user input and the value will be at around that area as well. the TimeRemaining gets a reset to it's max value after any input from the user.

The reason is because I want to kill a certain process if there was no user input in the last 5 minuets.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation It appears that the non idle value is the value of the system's sleep timer. note that in laptops it may change from DC to AC settings so you'll have to check that too.

How to get the sleep timer value I could not figure. but it gets more tricky, assume that your sleep timer is at 900, what happens after 900 seconds of idle pass is that the value resets itself to uint max and decreases from there. but as soon as there is user input, this value will get back to 900.

**The solution I ended with:**
Check the TimeRemaining every few seconds, if it remains the same for the last N checks, I will assume that this is the current non idle value.

The number of checks you will have to do before setting a new non idle value depends on the interval of your checks, that is because the TimeRemaining value updates every few seconds. in my case I check every 10 seconds and set it at 5 identical checks.

**This solution is not perfect**
Because in my application, I kill a certain process if the system is assume to be idle. I may acutely kill this process when the system is not idle, because it takes me at least 50 seconds to verify that the system is no longer idle.